# SQL selecting minimum value in a sub query when exact value is unknown

Tags: sql, min

I have an SQL query that is meant to select a list of things from different tables using a subquery. I am meant to find those things with the lowest value in a particular column.

This is the query that i currently have. I know the minimum rate is 350 but i cant use it in my query. Any effort to change it to MIN(rate) has been unsuccessful.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT name
  FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table2
  WHERE table2.code = (SELECT Code FROM rates WHERE rate = '100')
```

How do i change that subquery to find the minimum rate?

Comment: IS it in the same table.can you name that column?

Comment: what RDBMS you are using?

Comment: why have you used 100 ? is it just an example, or a real query considering minimum rate =100 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table2
WHERE table2.code = 
(SELECT CODE FROM RATE WHERE RATE=(SELECT MIN(RATE) FROM RATE))
```

Considering you are expecting only one record of minimum value.

Answer (score 3):

Most general way to do this would be

```
select distinct name
from table1 natural join table2
where
    table2.code in
    (
        select t.Code
        from rates as t
        where t.rate in (select min(r.rate) from rates as r)
    )
```

if you have windowed functions, you can use [`rank()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function:

```
...
where
    table2.code in
    (
        select t.Code
        from (
            select r.Code, rank() over(order by r.rate) as rn
            from rates as r
        ) as t
        where t.rn = 1
    )
```

in SQL Server you can use [`top ... with ties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) syntax:

```
...
where
    table2.code in
    (
        select top 1 with ties r.Code
        from rates as r
        order by r.rate
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
WHERE table2.code = (SELECT Code FROM rates ORDER BY rate LIMIT 1)
```